# Getting the HTML source through the WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to get HTML Source in the following way:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

but it does not work. For example, if the original HTML source is :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    Manufacturer</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

filter=1000036_3808675_100021_10194772_">Sony </a>(44)</li>
            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

filter=1000036_108496_100021_10194772_">Nikon </a>(19)</li>
            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

filter=1000036_3808726_100021_10194772_">Panasonic </a>(37)</li>
            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

filter=1000036_3808769_100021_10194772_">Canon </a>(29)</li>
            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

filter=1000036_2913388_100021_10194772_">Olympus </a>(21)</li>
            <li class="seeAll"><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?

sa=1000036&filter=100021_10194772_" class="readMore">See all manufacturers </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but the output of `webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml` is:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3>
                    Manufacturer</h3>
                <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?filter=1000036_3808675_100021_10194772_">Sony </a>(44)
                    <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?filter=1000036_108496_100021_10194772_">Nikon </a>(19)
                        <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?filter=1000036_3808726_100021_10194772_">Panasonic
                        </a>(37)
                            <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?filter=1000036_3808769_100021_10194772_">Canon </a>
                                (29)
                                <li><a href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?filter=1000036_2913388_100021_10194772_">Olympus </a>
                                    (21)
                                    <li class="seeAll"><a class="readMore" href="/4566-6501_7-0.html?sa=1000036&amp;filter=100021_10194772_">
                                        See all manufacturers </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

as you can see, many `</li>` are lost.

is there a way to get HTML source in `WebBrower` control correctly? Note that in my application, I try to use `WebBrowser` to add coordinate info to every node and output its HTML source with coordinate info which is added as attributes of nodes.

anybody can do me a favor?

Answer (score 10):

Try using [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) or [DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) properties.

Comment: yes,  both  DocumentText and DocumentStream can return correct HTML source. But when I add some attributes to nodes in DOM tree( myIHTMLElement.setAttribute() ), the HTML source got by WebBrowser1.DocumentText does not contain any added attributes

Comment: @Rockucqu, what about `InnerHtml` property - does that return correct html?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you all. My final solution is: first,using `body.outlineHtml` to get html source. because body.outlineHtml may miss end-tag for `<li>` and `<td>`, so the second step is using tidy to repair the HTML source. after these, we can get the HTML source without error

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `WebBrowser1.DocumentText`

Comment: yes,  WebBrowser1.DocumentText return correct HTML source. But when I add some attributes to nodes in DOM tree( myIHTMLElement.setAttribute() ), the HTML source got by WebBrowser1.DocumentText does not contain any added attributes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the entire HTML source of the WebBrowser control then use this - WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).OuterHtml.  This of course assumes you have properly formatted HTML and the HTML tag exists.  If you want to narrow it down to just the body then obviously change the HTML tag to the BODY tag.  This way you grab any and all changes after "DocumentText" has been set.  Sorry, I'm a VB guy, convert as needed ;)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this.
[WebBrowser on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx#Y199)

Alternative you could use `Webclient.DownloadString` from System.Net (it also has `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`...) Here is the description: [WebClient on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: in my application, I need to use WebBrowser to add coordinate info to every node and output its HTML source with coordinate info which is added as attributes of nodes.   Webclient can not perform this task