# Save HTML Source Code to string in WinForms Application

Tags: c#, html, dom

I need to get the source code from a website, which is structured in frames.

I already have a Windows Forms Application which has the WebBrowser function integrated into it.
When I do a right click and select "View Source" it opens a new text document with exactly the info I need.

I already tried `webBrowser.Document`, `webBrowser.DocumentText` and `webBrowser.DocumentStream`, but all of these only give me other info, I don't need.

The website is not static (it's a chat) and it does not do sessions, thus I can't use `Webclient.DownloadFile`.
I need to have an ongoing connection to the website for several hours without refreshing the website. I don't see a way around using the `webBrowser` in `Windows Forms`.

As requested, this is the website, I am talking about: http://server2.webkicks.de/stackoverflow-test/
You can just log in as a guest, by filling some username in the third textbox.

Comment: Do some research before posting Q please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download HTML source in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Why don't you just use `HttpClient` to download from a wesbite? https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient

Comment: @Tatranskymedved This actually does not help me a single bit

Comment: @Ali The website uses a login system, it is not static

Comment: I think `WebBrowser` or any Headless WebBrowsers like `CefSharp` isn't an answer for what you are doing.

I suggest you to take a look on this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183703/using-webclient-or-webrequest-to-login-to-a-website-and-access-data

Comment: That duplicate does exactly what your title asks for, gets html source. But modern webpages use *much* more than html

Comment: @Ali Thanks, I will look into that

Comment: @Sayse Well, it does not answer, what I describes in the question itself. The title is not the whole question, I believe

Comment: @Ali Sadly, this is not what I was looking for. The website, I'm trying to access, does not use sessions, so I need to uphold a connection after logging in and read new html every ~3 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the HTML source through the WebBrowser control in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164733/getting-the-html-source-through-the-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @sam I already saw this question on friday. It does not work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish to get the dynamic html content, and `webBrowser.Document`, `webBrowser.DocumentText` and `webBrowser.DocumentStream` are not working to your wish.

**Here's the trick**: You can always run your custom JavaScript code from C#. And here's how you can get the current HTML in your `WebBrowser` control:

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new string[]{"document.body.outerHTML"});
```

Refer to [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control/154496#154496).

**Update**

For `iframe` inside your `document`, you can try the following:

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new string[]{"document.querySelector(\"iframe\").contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML"});
```

**Another update**

As your site contains the `frame` instead of `iframe`, here is how you can get the html content of that `frame`:

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new string[]{"document.querySelector(\"frame[name='mainframe'\").contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML"});
```

**Final tested and working update**

`querySelector` is not working in `WebControl`. So the workaround is: Provide some `id` to your `<frame>`, and fetch that `<frame>` element using that `id`. Here is how you can achieve your task.

```
HtmlElement frame = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("frame").Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("name") == "mainframe");
if (frame != null)
{
    frame.Id = "RandID_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    string html = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('" + frame.Id + "').contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML" }).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(html);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Frame not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this does give me html source code, it is not the one, i was looking for. I think I need the source code of the frame, I am looking at.  
Injecting Javascript is the best way though, as you suggested

Comment: @TristanB. your ques. doesn't say `Iframe` anywhere.
No worry, I am updating the answer for iframe.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have trouble putting my problem into technical terms, as I am not a professional, but a learner. Thanks!

Comment: @TristanB. No problem. Sorry, if i discouraged you. I also did the similar thing once upon a time. lol. I have updated the answer. try once.

Comment: You did not discourage me, no worries. I tried your updated solution and it prints an empty new line into my file. Would it help, to see the website in question for yourself?

Comment: I edited the question. You can find the website there.

Comment: @TristanB. I have the updated the answer with **another update**. I hope this finally works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time to this point. This again prints an empty line. Maybe this is due to my printing method. Can I print the object from your answer by using The `WriteLine` method from `StreamWriter` to write it to a txt file?

Comment: @TristanB. I have updated the answer with **Final tested and working update**. Try once. It will work. :)

Comment: Awesome. It helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your website target use the ssl protocol (https) you can try adding the user-agent like this :

```
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
                            {
                                myWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");               
                                myWebClient.DownloadFile(new System.Uri("https://mywebsite.com//somefile"), "D:\\temp\\somefile");
                            }
```

If your website target needs login, then you log in into your websitetarget in chrome and use EditThisCookie extension to copy your cookies and try this one :

```
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
                            {
                                myWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
                                myWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "mycookies copies from EditThisCookie");
                                myWebClient.DownloadFile(new System.Uri("https://mywebsite.com//somefile"), "D:\\temp\\somefile");
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I don't need to download a file, but keep constant track of fast changing html. To even get to that html, I'm looking for, the website in question needs to be opened. If I close it, I will need to login again.
Does your answer work for these conditions?

Comment: For the first part of your question, you can try DownloadString instead of DownloadFile, and then try adding a while (true) and a Thread.Sleep(2000) inside it, which means you will check the content of your target page every 2000ms

Comment: For the second part, a cookie have an expiration date, wich means if it is expired you can no longer get the content of your target page, thus the only solution you got is to do it manually, to log in again , copy your cookies and insert them on your web client header.

Comment: I tried it now, by adding a copied cookie to the WebClient Header. This just gets me to the normal login page. I think, this web page does not work with cookies, or at least not in a helpful way for this scenario

Comment: If you close your browser, and re-open it again, do you need to log in again ?

Comment: Yes. Same for closing the tab

Comment: can you share with us the website link? i am really interested to know how it works and maybe i can find a solution for you since i am working on a similar project of downloading content from a ssl website

Comment: I have edited the question. The website link is there.